# ssh key and firewall blocked zone

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, firewalld

i added ssh key from servera to serverb

```
[production5@servera ~]$ ssh-copy-id production5@serverb
```

and i added servera to blocked  firewalld zone in serverb.

```
firewall-cmd --add-source=172.25.250.10/32 \
--zone=block --permanent
```

when i ssh from servera to serverb i can connect.

```
ssh -o pubkeyauthentication=yes \
-o passwordauthentication=no production5@serverb
```

didnt i just blocked servera how can servera ssh to serverb?